# How to change inspections column background color in PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm

Code inspections are highlighted on the right-side of the editor as red/yellow lines. I want to change the background color of the entire column (not the color of individual inspections).

In previous versions of PhpStorm (with the Darcula theme), the column was a grey color. In PhpStorm 10, it is now transparent. Is there a way to change the background color?

[image: 8.0.3]

[image: 10.0]

Comment: Bonus points if anyone can tell me why I have so much extra space between the line numbers and the tear line (i.e. expand/collapse labels) in the left-side gutter. The file has < 1000 lines, so I'm not sure what's creating the extra space.

Comment: Look for icons (like `(I)` or `(o)` and similar) -- most likely because of them.

Comment: What's the purpose of the (I), (o) icons? I don't see any of those, but my guess is that something's visible in the gutter but colored black.

Comment: That's for PHP and other languages where you have class inheritance / method overriding etc. Not sure about HTML though (what can be displayed here)...

Comment: It's there with JS and CSS files too. My only guess was something with version control, but I haven't figured it out yet.

Answer (score 1):

Not really. **That color is part of the IDE Theme which is not user configurable.**

But you can show **some** background there:

1. `Help | Find Action...`
2. Look for `Registry` there (exact match)
3. Once got inside Registry window look for `editor.transparent.scrollbar` and uncheck it (user modified values will be displayed in bold .. so make sure you have changed it, not just "Click and that's enough")

Comment: That's what I'm looking for! I don't see any user modified values, though, just the ability to check or uncheck the option. With it unchecked, it has a black background color, but I'd like to make it something else.

Comment: Changing default value to your own (even simple switch between true/false (or on/off)) means that user have modified the original (default) value.

Comment: Ok. Your answer only partially solves the question, so I won't select it as "correct," but I definitely appreciate the effort (hence the up-vote). Thanks for the help!

Comment: Whatever. But the answer is already in the answer -- you CANNOT change that color unless you modify GUI Theme itself.